# Exception : (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

From now on (a few weeks or so), when I create a Facebook app on the Facebook for Developers console and then I call Facebook Graph API, I'm getting an error message about "Page Public Content Access" described below:

**Steps:**

**1.** I have created an app, automatically set to **API version 3.0**, and I'm using the **app ID** and **app secret** information provided in the Facebook Developer Console. 
I want to get posts data from my own page (not profile) I have created with my Facebook account, and display its recent posts on a web page.

**2.** To get my data from Facebook, I'm using the official Facebook PHP SDK, and I'm requesting the following URL : 
**[https:]//graph.facebook.com/mypageID/posts?access_token=myappID|myappSecret**

**3.** When I call the API, I'm getting the following error message :

> Exception : (#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint >must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content >Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: >[https:]//developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.

**My question is :** *Using PHP SDK for Facebook, is it now mandatory, since last Facebook update (April 24th), to have the app reviewed, even when for a simple posts request on my own page?*

If this is the case, is there any alternative, still using the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 2):

For getting the posts of your own Page, you just need to use a Page Token and keep the App in dev mode. Right now you are using an App Token though, that will not work unless you go through a review process. You can use a Page Token for your Page to avoid that process.

For posts of Pages you do not own, you must go through the review process for "[Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

More information about Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. 

Even in dev mode, it seems that I still need an access token. 

I got it working by requesting a long-lived token here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

So far I only found one almost viable solution here : https://elfsight.com/blog/2017/10/how-to-get-facebook-access-token/

Or am I missing something?

Comment: of course you need an access token. you always need one. for every api call. read my answer again and make sure you know the difference between app token and page token.

Comment: Until now, my apps did not use a token, I could get posts without restrictions, and for my apps created before April 24th, they still work fine.

I'm worried of what will happen on August 1st for these apps, am I going to loose access to the posts? Or will I need to either 1) ask validation or 2) migrate them in dev mode and request an access token for each of them?

Comment: i am not sure what else to tell you, to be honest. everything you need to know is in my answer already. there are 2 solutions, it just depends if you own the page or not. again, make sure you know about the different tokens. APP token is different than PAGE token.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a Page token here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and I can call posts as I'm the owner, it's now working. However, I still wonder what is going to happen for my apps created before April 24th.

Comment: they will lose access if you are not using a page token and don´t get them reviewed